# Play! 2.0 performance metrics

Tags: performance, scala, metrics, playframework-2.0

I'm developing my first application for Play! 2.0 framework. It feels really nice, love akka actors but one thing I'm looking for is something where I could hook some performance metrics on. What I'm looking for is Rails notifications like [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html) or something like Twitter's [finagle](http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/searchbird.html) offers (look for curl command used to retrieve stats.txt).

Is there anything baked in in Play! 2.0? or should I start cooking something on my own? If there isn't anything ready - any pointers and tips are welcome!

Comment: From akka-side one option is typesafe console. How about from Play!? Since it's based on akka I take it that typesafe console is also the answer? There isn't higher level statistics available from Play! itself?

Answer (score 2):

The official way of getting Akka performance metrics is the following: http://typesafe.com/products/console

Comment: I've looked at console. Is it possible to forward monitoring data from the console? we have several requirements regarding notifications (like sending audit info every x-number of messages, sending information for accounting purposes etc).

Comment: The console only visualizes the data captured by the instrumentation. There's are APIs to extract data from the aggregator so you can use it for hooking into your own apps.

Comment: Ah, that sounds good. I read through your website but I'd just wanted to make sure that it is possible to deploy console/agents/all in completelty isolated environment which does not have any access to outside world? (yeah - we do have some crazy security policies in place....)

Comment: Yup, that should be just fine :-)

Comment: That's excellent. Thanks for your answers and keep up the good work with Akka. It's excellent!

Comment: Console is no longer supported. The recommended solutions from typesafe are from AppDynamics or New Relic.

Answer (score 1):

While I have not used it in a Play! scala app, I've been a big fan of [Newrelic](http://newrelic.com) for all the performance metrics in production. That said, I do not think it'd be any different with a Play! war. It will give you basic metrics with a free account. For most of my scala apps I use the newrelic annotations to collect metrics around a particular method that I'd want to track in detail - I've seen newrelic give much detailed results with Java than Scala, hence the annotations.

Comment: I'd love to use newrelic. Unfortunately servers I'm deploying are behind firewalls and no outbound connections are allowed due to security reasons. I've tried to change this policy but that's a battle which reminds Don Quijote going against windmills.

Answer (score 0):

There is a statsd play2 plugin: https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/statsd
Or Codahale's Metrics Play2 plugin: https://github.com/kenshoo/metrics-play

I'm looking at the metrics one to provide JMX data out at the moment although if statsd is an option, you might want to look at that first.